# How to train a LSTM model with different N-dimensions labels?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am using keras (ver. 2.0.6 with TensorFlow backend) for a simple neural network:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(32, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(100, 5)))
model.add(LSTM(32, return_sequences=True)) 
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(5)))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='rmsprop',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

It is only a test for me, I am "training" the model with the following dummy data.

```
x_train = np.array([
    [[0,0,0,0,1], [0,0,0,1,0], [0,0,1,0,0]],
    [[1,0,0,0,0], [0,1,0,0,0], [0,0,1,0,0]],
    [[0,1,0,0,0], [0,0,1,0,0], [0,0,0,1,0]],
    [[0,0,1,0,0], [1,0,0,0,0], [1,0,0,0,0]],
    [[0,0,0,1,0], [0,0,0,0,1], [0,1,0,0,0]],
    [[0,0,0,0,1], [0,0,0,0,1], [0,0,0,0,1]]
])

y_train = np.array([
    [[0,0,0,0,1], [0,0,0,1,0], [0,0,1,0,0]],
    [[1,0,0,0,0], [0,1,0,0,0], [0,0,1,0,0]],
    [[0,1,0,0,0], [0,0,1,0,0], [0,0,0,1,0]],
    [[1,0,0,0,0], [1,0,0,0,0], [1,0,0,0,0]],
    [[1,0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0,1], [0,1,0,0,0]],
    [[1,0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0,1], [0,0,0,0,1]]
])
```

then i do:

```
model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=2, epochs=50, shuffle=False)

print(model.predict(x_train))
```

The result is:

```
[[[ 0.11855114  0.13603994  0.21069065  0.28492314  0.24979511]
  [ 0.03013871  0.04114409  0.16499813  0.41659597  0.34712321]
  [ 0.00194826  0.00351031  0.06993906  0.52274817  0.40185428]]

 [[ 0.17915446  0.19629011  0.21316603  0.22450975  0.18687972]
  [ 0.17935558  0.1994358   0.22070852  0.2309722   0.16952793]
  [ 0.18571526  0.20774922  0.22724937  0.23079531  0.14849086]]

 [[ 0.11163659  0.13263632  0.20109797  0.28029731  0.27433187]
  [ 0.02216373  0.03424517  0.13683401  0.38068131  0.42607573]
  [ 0.00105937  0.0023865   0.0521594   0.43946937  0.50492537]]

 [[ 0.13276921  0.15531689  0.21852671  0.25823513  0.23515201]
  [ 0.05750636  0.08210614  0.22636817  0.3303588   0.30366054]
  [ 0.01128351  0.02332032  0.210263    0.3951444   0.35998878]]

 [[ 0.15303896  0.18197381  0.21823004  0.23647803  0.21027911]
  [ 0.10842207  0.15755147  0.23791778  0.26479205  0.23131666]
  [ 0.06472684  0.12843341  0.26680911  0.28923658  0.25079405]]

 [[ 0.19560908  0.20663913  0.21954383  0.21920268  0.15900527]
  [ 0.22829761  0.22907974  0.22933882  0.20822221  0.10506159]
  [ 0.27179539  0.25587022  0.22594844  0.18308094  0.063305  ]]]
```

Ok, It works, but it is just a test, i really do not care about accuracy etc. I would like to understand how i can work with output of different size.

For example: passing a sequence (numpy.array) like:

```
[[0,0,0,0,1], [0,0,0,1,0], [0,0,1,0,0]]
```

I would like to get 4 dimensions output as prediction:

```
[[..first..], [..second..], [..third..], [..four..]]
```

Is that possibile somehow? The size could vary I would train the model with different labels that can have different N-dimensions.

Thanks

Comment: Do you actually want four-dimensional output or do you mean three-dimensional output with four timesteps?

Comment: Additionally, you should provide runnable code. The above code would fail as your `input_shape` is `(100, 5)` but each sample in `x_train` has shape `(3, 5)`.

Comment: My wrong... i meant four timesteps!

Comment: Okay, and you're saying a single `y_train` can have a variable number of timesteps?

Comment: Exactly @NicoleWhite

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer is for non varying dimensions, but for varying dimensions, the **padding** idea in Giuseppe's answer seems the way to go, maybe with help of the ["Masking"](https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/) proposed in Keras documentation.

---

The output shape in Keras is totally dependent on the number of "units/neurons/cells" you put in the last layer, and of course, on the type of layer.

I can see that your data does not match your code in your question, it's impossible, but, suppose your code is right and forget the data for a while.

An **input shape of (100,5)** in an LSTM layer means a tensor of shape `(None, 100, 5)`, which is

- `None` is the batch size. The first dimension of your data is reserved to the **number of examples** you have. (X and Y must have the same number of examples).
- Each example is a `sequence with 100 time steps`
- each time step is a `5-dimension vector`.

And the **32 cells** in this same LSTM layer means that the resulting vectors will change from 5 to 32-dimension vectors. With `return_sequences=True`, all the 100 timesteps will appear in the result. So the result shape of the first layer is `(None, 100, 32)`:

- Same number of examples (this will never change along the model)
- Still 100 timesteps per example (because `return_sequences=True`)
- each time step is a 32-dimension vector (because of 32 cells)

**Now the second LSTM layer** does exactly the same thing. Keeps the 100 timesteps, and since it has also 32 cells, keeps the 32-dimension vectors, so the output is also `(None, 100, 32)`

**Finally, the time distributed Dense layer** will also keep the 100 timesteps (because of `TimeDistributed`), and change your vectors to 5-dimensoin vectors again (because of `5 units`), resulting in `(None, 100, 5)`.

---

As you can see, you cannot change the number of timesteps directly with recurrent layers, you need to use other layers to change these dimensions. And the way to do this is completely up to you, there are infinite ways of doing this.

But in all of them, you need to get free of the timesteps and rebuild the data with another shape.

---

### Suggestion

**A suggestion** from me (which is just one possibility) is to reshape your result, and apply another dense layer just to achieve the final shape expeted.

Suppose you want a result like `(None, 4, 5)` (never forget, the first dimension of your data is the number of **examples**, it can be any number, but you must take it into account when you organize your data). We can achieve this by reshaping the data to a shape containing 4 in the second dimension:

```
#after the Dense layer:

model.add(Reshape((4,125)) #the batch size doesn't appear here, 
   #just make sure you have 500 elements, which is 100*5 = 4*125

model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(5))
#this layer could also be model.add(LSTM(5,return_sequences=True)), for instance

#continue to the "Activation" layer
```

This will give you 4 timesteps (because the dimension after Reshape was: (None, 4, 125), each step being a 5-dimension vector (because of Dense(5)).

Use the `model.summary()` command to see the shapes outputted by each layer.

Comment: Thank you! But i have a doubt regarding the time steps, I have followed your advice, i have tested the Reshape() layer that is working just fine, please take a look at: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/4c8c04ad25ef349be5e9ebaec4c5830c as you can see the summary looks promising, it shows the different shape. However the problem cames when i try to fit() the data (line 33). It is waiting the same number of time steps as the input so i really cannot use Reshape. What have i forgotten?

Comment: I can't see your code right now, but it's waiting the same number of "examples". If the error message says "target" the problem is in "Y", if it says "input(s)", the problem is in "X". ---- First, "X" and "Y" should have the same number of "examples/samples" (the first dimension). Each example in X should give one result in Y, always. The second dimension, which is the timesteps, is only related to the "input_dimension" for X and to the last layer's output for Y.

Comment: Supposing your `input_shape=(100,5)`, and that you have 6000 examples for training, X must shaped like `(6000, 100, 5)`. If you have only one example, X must be like `(1,100,5)`. Now, supposing your output shape is `(None, 4, 5)`, Y must be shaped like `(6000,4,5)`, respecting: rule 1 - same number of examples as in X; rule 2 - the output shape of the last layer. (Each example is an entire sequence).

Answer (score 2):

I don't know Keras but from a practical and theoretical point of view this is absolutely possible.

The idea is that you have an *input sequence* and an *output sequence*. Commonly, the beginning and the end of each sequence are delimited by some special symbol (e.g. the character sequence "cat" is translated into "^cat#" with an start symbol "^" and an end symbol "#"). Then the sequence is padded with another special symbol, up to a *maximum sequence length* (e.g. "^cat#$$$$$$" with a padding symbol "$").

If the padding symbol correspond to a zero-vector, it will have no impact on your training.

Your output sequence could now assume any length up to the maximum one, because the real length is the one from the start to the end symbol positions.

In other words, you will have always the same input and output sequence length (i.e. the maximum one), but the real length is that between the start and the end symbols.

(Obviously, in the output sequence, anything after the end symbol should not be considered in the loss function)

Comment: What DL library are you using? Yes i can use a delimiter to understand the start and the end of the sequence, but i am not able to replicate it in Keras. I found examples that are padding the sequence with zeros but the total length is fixes, so i think i should set a MAX length and pad it if the sentence is shorter.

Comment: I use tensorflow, but usually I find easier to make this preprocessing step (padding, ect) directly in python before providing it to tensorflow (however, there are some tensorflow functions to do it automatically)

Comment: Yes, sounds better... I also use tensorflow as backend but how do you pad the sequence? because if you pad the sentence it means that you are using the same (fixed) vector lenght with zeros for short sequences.

Comment: Giuseppe the problem is that using a seq2seq approach the input (question) should be short, the answer very long (i do not know the length) so how can i pad it?

Comment: In a mini-batch approach there is no way to avoid long paddings: just pad everything to a maximum length that will be hardly overcome by your answers. Truncated BPTT (Back-Propagation Through Time) via State Saver of the question above explain you how to handle long inputs. For long outputs, since you don't know the length of your answer, you can't use a similar apporach. In an online scenario, you can just check if your answer presents the stop symbol. If not provide a new blank input and restore the last state of the RNN.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be two methods to do a sequence to sequence method, you're describing. The first directly using keras using [this example](https://blog.keras.io/building-autoencoders-in-keras.html) (code below)

```
from keras.layers import Input, LSTM, RepeatVector
from keras.models import Model

inputs = Input(shape=(timesteps, input_dim))
encoded = LSTM(latent_dim)(inputs)

decoded = RepeatVector(timesteps)(encoded)
decoded = LSTM(input_dim, return_sequences=True)(decoded)

sequence_autoencoder = Model(inputs, decoded)
encoder = Model(inputs, encoded)
```

Where the repeat vector repeats the initial time series n times to match the output vectors number of timestamps. This will still mean you need a fixed number of time steps in you output vector, however, there may be a method to padding vectors that have less timestamps than you max amount of timesteps.

Or you can you the [seq2seq](https://github.com/farizrahman4u/seq2seq) module, which is built ontop of keras.